# how to write javascript validation for dropdown selected index changed event in c#

Tags: c#

I have a dropdown.Basing on this dropdown i shud load another dropdown.i wrote code in on selected index changed event in .cs page.Depending on selectd item in first dropdown i need to give a validation in javascript.let us think i should show an alert.Can any one help me out.

in .aspx page

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpdes" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="drpdes_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

in .cs page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         drpdes.AutoPostBack = true;
    }

 protected void drpdes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         int flgchk = 0;
          if(drpdes.selectedvalue == "0")
           {
                flgchk = 1;
           }
        // my code for binding second dropdown
    }
```

when flgchk = 1 i need to show an alert from javascript.i wrote a function for alert in javascript.But i am not understanding where to call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this :)

```
protected void drpdes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         int flgchk = 0;
          if(drpdes.selectedvalue == "0")
           {
                flgchk = 1;
              /// this will call your alert method. 
                string errorScript = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">" + 
                      "YourFunctionNameHere() " + 
                      "</script>";
                    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", errorScript);
           }
        // my code for binding second dropdown
    }
```

Comment: @prema better you can write your function in this block only, rather than calling different functions. , check updated answer,

Comment: I tried ur way but it is not working Ravi.can u suggest any other way.i tried directly writing the function there itself.it is not calling.

Comment: it will work. as i tried in my page. and you do include your javascrip function in your aspx. in <script> tag.

Comment: do i need to give any semicolon at end or function at starting.i am not able to get this

Comment: my javascript function is there in <asp:content><script>function</script></asp:content>.Is this a problem for not getting

Comment: you can replace your code in this function block na, rather than calling different fucntion .

Comment: i replaced and tested.it is not calling.u told me to place it in aspx page in ur previous comment.pls check

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7000/discussion-between-ravi-and-prema)

Answer (score 0):

If you remove AutoPostback on your dropdownlist you can validate client side. Something like onchange = YourJSMethod(this.value).

Comment: but i need the method in .cs page also know.for that i need autopostback true know

Comment: In that case see Ravis answer below.